# Как написать код с помощью Entry, разрешающий писать только цифры?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tcl, validate

Как в поле ввода (`Entry`) сделать запрет на написание букв? 
То есть, чтобы можно было писать только цифры.

**main.py**:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Okno")
frm_form = tk.Frame(relief=tk.SUNKEN, borderwidth=3)
frm_form.pack()

que = tk.Label(master=frm_form, text="VVedite")
ans = tk.Entry(master=frm_form, width=100)
que.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")
ans.grid(row=0, column=1)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45005240/checking-for-numeric-inputs-in-a-entry-widget-tkinter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все механизмы проверки подробно описаны в документации tcl здесь:
http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/entry.htm#M7

Попробуйте так:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Okno")

def validate(new_value):                                                  # +++
    return new_value == "" or new_value.isnumeric()                       # +++

que = tk.Label(window, text="Введите цифры")

vcmd = (window.register(validate), '%P')                                  # +++
ans = tk.Entry(window, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)              # +++

que.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")
ans.grid(row=0, column=1)
ans.focus()

window.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как можно сделать запрет на написание символов, кроме 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 и ".". Можно как-нибудь сделать маску?

Comment: @CATpython это уже другой вопрос, задайте пожалуйста новый вопрос. Приведите пример и хорошо распишите, какую маску вы хотите получить. Важен ли вам знак числа (`-` / `+`) или число без знака? Нужно ли ограничивать вводимое число до какого-то значения (`99999`)? Нежно ли ограничивать вводимое число (значение после запятой `99999.999`) ? и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо! ,,,,,,,,